# Helm Keycloak Postgres ERROR: column "client_id" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, schema, keycloak, kubernetes-helm

I followed this [guide](https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/tree/master/incubator/keycloak) to Config Keycloak + Postgres use Helm.

I have tried with H2 database (default), it works fine. And then, I config to use with Postgres, below is my config.

```
keycloak:
  replicas: 1

  image:
    repository: jboss/keycloak
    tag: 3.4.0.Final
  username: admin
  password: admin
  service:
    type: LoadBalancer
  persistence:
    deployPostgres: false
    dbVendor: POSTGRES

    dbName: keycloak
    dbHost: xxx.pgsql.domain.com
    dbPort: 5432
    dbUser: keycloak

    # Only used if no existing secret is specified. In this case a new secret is created
    dbPassword: xxxxxxxxxx
```

Seem the connection fine, but the error logs:

```
7:18:24,071 ERROR [org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.conn.DefaultLiquibaseConnectionProvider] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) Change Set META-INF/jpa-changelog-authz-3.4.0.CR1.xml::authz-3.4.0.CR1-resource-server-pk-change-part2::glavoie@gmail.com failed.  Error: ERROR: column "client_id" does not exist
  Position: 73 [Failed SQL: UPDATE RESOURCE_SERVER_POLICY p SET RESOURCE_SERVER_CLIENT_ID = (SELECT CLIENT_ID FROM RESOURCE_SERVER s WHERE s.ID = p.RESOURCE_SERVER_ID)]: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: column "client_id" does not exist
  Position: 73 [Failed SQL: UPDATE RESOURCE_SERVER_POLICY p SET RESOURCE_SERVER_CLIENT_ID = (SELECT CLIENT_ID FROM RESOURCE_SERVER s WHERE s.ID = p.RESOURCE_SERVER_ID)]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:316)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:55)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:122)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.execute(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1247)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1230)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:548)
    at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:51)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:73)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:210)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:190)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:186)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.updateChangeSet(LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.java:135)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.update(LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.java:88)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.update(LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.java:67)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.update(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:322)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.migration(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:308)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.lambda$lazyInit$0(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:179)
    at org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.suspendJtaTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:544)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.lazyInit(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:130)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.create(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:78)
    at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.create(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:56)
    at org.keycloak.services.DefaultKeycloakSession.getProvider(DefaultKeycloakSession.java:163)
    at org.keycloak.models.jpa.JpaRealmProviderFactory.create(JpaRealmProviderFactory.java:51)
    at org.keycloak.models.jpa.JpaRealmProviderFactory.create(JpaRealmProviderFactory.java:33)
    at org.keycloak.services.DefaultKeycloakSession.getProvider(DefaultKeycloakSession.java:163)
    at org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.RealmCacheSession.getDelegate(RealmCacheSession.java:144)
    at org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.RealmCacheSession.getMigrationModel(RealmCacheSession.java:137)
    at org.keycloak.migration.MigrationModelManager.migrate(MigrationModelManager.java:74)
    at org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.migrateModel(KeycloakApplication.java:244)
    at org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.migrateAndBootstrap(KeycloakApplication.java:185)
    at org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication$1.run(KeycloakApplication.java:144)
    at org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.runJobInTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:227)
    at org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.<init>(KeycloakApplication.java:135)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:150)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.createProviderInstance(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:2298)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.createApplication(ResteasyDeployment.java:340)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:253)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:120)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(HttpServletDispatcher.java:36)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:250)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:133)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:565)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:536)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:578)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "client_id" does not exist
  Position: 73
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2477)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2190)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:300)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:428)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:354)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:301)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:287)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:264)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:260)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedStatement.execute(WrappedStatement.java:198)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:314)
    ... 65 more

17:18:24,096 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./auth: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./auth: java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003325: Failed to construct public org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication(javax.servlet.ServletContext,org.jboss.resteasy.core.Dispatcher)
    at org.wild...
```

Please help me to fix it. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The chart has several places where it expects

```
deployPostgres: true
```

when using postgres.

Comment: Thanks, I would like to use external Postgres from Cloud. Any idea?

Comment: Ok, so deployPostgres should be false. The error message indicates that liquibase is unable to perform a database migration. Hard to diagnose, probably best to start over.

Comment: Yes, I have no idea for now. Could you please think about it and help me?

Comment: How did you create the cloud database?

Comment: I create RDS on Alibaba Cloud. It works fine before when I use Kubernetes + Postgres. Now I move to helm to implement something more.

Comment: helm works with kubernetes resource files, same as kubectl. use the --dry-run flag with helm to have it produce yaml files rather than changing the cluster. then review the files to see what is different from the time when it worked. The helm chart- just templated yaml files- probably has bugs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167378/discussion-between-workwe-and-jonah-benton).